# Variable increment in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

i've an xml file like

```
<node>
 <elm val="data1"/>
 <elm val="data2"/>
 <elm val="data3"/>
 <elm val="data4"/>
 <elm val="data5"/>
 <elm val="data6"/>
 <elm val="data7"/>
</node>
```

i need to write an xslt for this xml file to display in a table fomat like

```
  1 dat1
  2 dat2
  3 dat3
  4 dat4
  5 dat5
  6 dat6
  7 dat7
```

please help me to do this

Comment: What XSLT do you have so far?

Comment: Good Question (+1). See my answer for a correct and complete solution. Understand why Oded's solution is... WRONG. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<xsl:tempate match="node">
  <table>
    <xsl:call-template select="elm"/>
  </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="elm">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::elm) + 1"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="@val"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

Alternatively if the exact ouput is required use the following template for `elm`.

```
<xsl:template match="elm">
  <xsl:param name="pos" select="count(preceding-sibling::elm) + 1"/>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="$pos"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <xsl:text>dat</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="$pos"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

Or in case of text output:

```
<xsl:tempate match="node">
  <xsl:foreach select="elm">
     <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::elm) + 1"/>
     <xsl:text> dat</xsl:text>
     <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::elm) + 1"/>
     <xsl:text  disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;#xA;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:foreach>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2):

**This is wrong**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="elm">
     <xsl:value-of select="concat(position(), ' ', @val)"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When run with many XSLT processors this will produce the following (unwanted) output**:

```
 2 data1
 4 data2
 6 data3
 8 data4
 10 data5
 12 data6
 14 data7
```

**The reason is** that when templates are applied to the children of the top element, this includes the children that are white-space-only text nodes -- between every two consecutive `elm` elements.

**So, Oded's solution is wrong**.

**Here is one correct solution** (and one of the shortest possible):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="elm">
     <xsl:value-of select="concat(position(), ' ', @val, '&#xA;')"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**This transformation produces the correct result**:

```
1 data1
2 data2
3 data3
4 data4
5 data5
6 data6
7 data7
```

**Do note**:

1. **The use of the `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>`** to direct the XSLT processor to discard any white-space-only text nodes.
2. **The use of the XPath `concat()` function** to glue together the position, the data and the NL character.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`position()`](http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/function_position.html) function

```
<xsl:template match="elm">
   <xsl:value-of select="concat(position(), ' ', @val)" />
</xsl:template>
```

Note: The table format in your example does not match the value of the `val` attribute, but I have assumed that you want both to be the same (output of first line should be `1 data1` instead of `1 dat1`.

As @Dimitre Novatchev noted in his answer, this assumes that your original document has no white-space-only nodes. In his answer he deals with this by removing all white-space-only nodes from the input document (using the `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` directive) and appending a new line character (`&#xA;`) at the end of the concatenation.

Comment: See here (dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N6099.html) for a reason why position is not ideal.

Comment: @Obalix - in this case, `position()` is fine, as the context node is `elm`.

Comment: Why the downvote? `position()` may be misunderstood by some, but is a perfectly fine function to use in certain circumstances, including this one.

Comment: See my answer to understand the flaw in your proposed solution. Never post a solution without having actually performed the transformation -- this will save both your time and that of the readers. More importantly, they will not be misled to use an incorrect solution.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev - thanks for the feedback and information. Answer updated to include white-space-only nodes information.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="node">
   <table>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="elm"/>
   </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="elm">
   <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></td>
      <td>dat<xsl:value-of select="position()"/></td>
   </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: See here (http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N6099.html) for a reason why position is not ideal.

Answer (score -1):

XSLT "variables" are unvarying variables. Once you set them, you can't arbitrarily change them.

The only hacks around it is to use the position() function and other "+1" functions, but you don't get the flexibility of a true variable.

There are many articles about the unvariability of XSLT "variables".

Quoting article on "http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/02/07/trxml9.html"

> XSLT variables actually have a lot more in common with constants in many programming languages and are used for a similar purpose.

Counters in XSLT are not possible because XSLT is not a procedural language, it's declarative. To the downvoter: please provide reason. If this is wrong, then please prove otherwise.